# How do I find the largets item in an array with php (specifically, largest taxonomy_id in an array of ids)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to return the highest term taxonomy id of a post page or a taxonomy page.

I was sucessful at listing all taxonomy id's like this:

```
  <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'mytaxonomy' );
if($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->term_taxonomy_id;
    }
}
?>
```

This is what I am trying to do (return only the highest ID) (doesn't work):

```
   <?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'mytaxonomy' );
if($terms) {

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    echo max( '$term->term_taxonomy_id');
    }

}
?>
```

Please help :)

NOTE:
My main goal is to make this work: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9562/multi-level-taxonomy-navigation

Answer (score 0):

The max function can probably compare only two terms at a time. Keep track of the maximum term as you go through the loop - maybe:

maximum_term = max(maximum_term,term->term_taxonomy_id);

Comment: I think it worked, thanks! I am just going to check again to make sure :)

Comment: nevermind, when I put this`$maximum_term = max(maximum_term,term-term_taxonomy_id);
echo $maximum_term;` It ouputs "maximumterm"

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the loop at all just apply max to the $terms variable

Comment: Just to add ref here - use php's internal function like: max($termIds), which should return the maxium ID from the array. Assuming array has all integer values. For more info see - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Comment: it didn't work because not all array values are integer (in this case). The array is composed from different return values which go from integer to full text description : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: I tried again, it gives me : Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in...

Comment: Ok yes sorry, assumed integers